# Lightning Community Builder: Can I move (ChangeSet/Migration Tool?) a PAGE from Sandbox Community to Production?

Tags: deployment, migration-tool, community-builder

Okay so, I know that I can use the Migration Tool to pull down **Lightning Components** from my sandbox, and then use the same tool to upload them to production, but so far I have had no luck in moving a single **PAGE** from my community site in my sandbox over to our community site in production. I've searched online but am having trouble finding any documentation or instructions specific enough for this scenario.

We are using the Lightning Community Builder, so the page itself is created within the Community Builder, and the content of the page is a series of lightning components, text boxes, HTML, styling, and images.

I'd like to move that entire page (and only that page) to our production environment, to avoid the need to re-create it manually and put all of the lightning components back on the page, copy/paste all of the text areas, images, etc into Production.

These pages don't appear under the "*Visualforce Pages*" or "*Visualforce Components*" sections - the only place I seem to find them is **IN** the Community Builder itself. As of now, I am able to get the Lightning Components into production, but I still end up re-creating the page in production and manually dragging all of the components back into the right place.

> **Question:** This is tedious of course, is there a better way to get a
>   single Lightning Community Builder page pushed into production?

Comment: Morgan, I do have the same issue, could you find a solution ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot use changesets with community builder pages currently .

Using force.com migration tool you can transfer the metadata of site.com and Network .

There is a Pilot program running which allows you to export a template and provides more flexibility around packaging .You may want to reach out to our AE and take advantage of the same for community builder . Please note a safe Harbour and all the rules of Pilot program applies here .

Comment: I believe Site.com can be moved with Changesets now; but not Network. However. Site.com is just the Community Name so not very useful.

Comment: I think even Network can be deployed via change sets now. Just wondering if it overwrites all existing pages of that community or updates it with new ones. Does anybody have this information?